# How can I avoid CSS flickering when hovering over areas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I updated my html+[css](http://avantgardecssfiddlezzz.montaoproject.appspot.com/static/css/koolindex_in.css) and now I get flickering when moving the cursor over the map areas. I created a fiddle with the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/e0a4sb5g/

I read that I can either change the css and html or put in a z-value. I tried that but it's still flickering when moving the cursor over the map areas. If I move the cursor over the region text to the left it is not flickering. Can you please tell me what I can do about it? I didn't have this problem before I changed a lot of CSS.

[image][image]

```
<div class="column_left">
    <div class="box">

        <ul>
            <li>free.</li>

        </ul>


    </div>

    <div id="regions">


        <div class="region_links_one">
            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/andhra_pradesh/">Andhra
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/arunachal_pradesh/">Arunachal
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/assam/">Assam</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/bihar/">Bihar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/chhattisgarh/">Chhattisgarh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/goa/">Goa</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/gujarat/">Gujarat</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/haryana/">Haryana</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_16" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/himachal_pradesh/">Himachal
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_17" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/jammu_kashmir/">Jammu
                    &amp;
                    Kashmir</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_18" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/jharkhand/">Jharkhand</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_19" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/karnataka/">Karnataka</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_20" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/kerala/">Kerala</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_21" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/madhya_pradesh/">Madhya
                    Pradesh</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a id="region_22" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/maharashtra/">Maharashtra</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_23" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/manipur/">Manipur</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_24" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/meghalaya/">Meghalaya</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_25" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/mizoram/">Mizoram</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_26" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/nagaland/">Nagaland</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_27" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/orissa/">Orissa</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_28" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/punjab/">Punjab</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_29" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/rajasthan/">Rajasthan</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_30" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/sikkim/">Sikkim</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_31" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/tamil_nadu/">Tamil
                    Nadu</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_32" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/tripura/">Tripura</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_34" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/uttaranchal/">Uttaranchal</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_33" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/uttar_pradesh/">Uttar
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_35" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/west_bengal/">West
                    Bengal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="region_links_two">
            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <!-- v22 -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                 style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:15px"
                 data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
                 data-ad-slot="1596572194"></ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
            <h2>Union territories</h2>


            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/delhi/">Delhi</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/lakshadweep/">Lakshadweep</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/daman_diu/">Daman &amp; Diu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/dadra_nagar_haveli/">Dadra &amp; Nagar
                    Haveli</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/chandigarh/">Chandigarh</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/pondicherry/">Pondicherry</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/andaman_nicobar_islands/">Andaman &amp;
                    Nicobar
                    Islands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="mapcontainer">

    <div class="sprite_index_in_in_map">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOPr+AAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
             id="area_highlight" alt="">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOPr+AAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" id="area_map"
             usemap="#map_map_map" alt="">
   </div>
    <map name="map_map_map" id="map_map_map">


        <area tabindex="-1" shape="poly" id="hoverregion_8"
              coords="261,310,251,322,240,333,234,337,229,340,225,343,223,347,221,352,220,356,217,356,212,356,207,356,205,358,204,361,201,365,197,364,193,364,191,365,188,369,187,376,187,381,188,384,186,389,185,394,185,398,187,402,187,405,184,403,182,406,181,408,178,408,174,409,172,410,169,412,165,412,162,412,160,415,158,418,155,420,156,414,157,410,157,405,155,401,151,398,147,397,143,397,140,399,136,399,133,398,133,393,132,388,130,384,129,380,131,377,133,375,136,375,137,374,136,370,136,365,137,362,141,362,142,359,142,354,141,350,140,344,141,339,143,337,145,334,144,330,144,325,145,321,145,317,146,315,148,309,151,305,154,300,158,297,164,297,169,298,172,299,178,300,182,299,184,299,183,305,184,310,184,313,188,315,192,317,196,321,199,324,201,327,204,330,206,331,211,330,215,328,219,327,223,327,223,322,225,318,229,318,232,320,234,322,232,316,235,314,239,313,240,310,243,307,245,310,248,312,252,313,254,313,256,310,258,308,262,308,263,308"
              href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/andhra_pradesh/6" alt="Andhra Pradesh">
     ...
        <area tabindex="-1" shape="poly" id="hoverregion_35"
              coords="321,165,319,166,317,166,315,168,312,168,308,167,308,169,310,173,311,175,312,177,311,179,309,180,311,181,309,185,306,187,305,189,306,192,308,194,308,196,306,199,305,201,306,203,308,204,309,206,310,208,309,211,306,216,304,219,298,221,293,223,292,226,290,229,288,232,284,230,280,231,278,234,279,236,281,239,286,240,290,243,294,247,295,250,295,252,294,254,294,255,301,261,306,264,308,262,311,258,315,256,317,258,318,258,322,256,324,254,328,253,329,253,328,248,326,243,326,240,326,235,327,234,323,232,322,230,321,226,323,222,324,219,323,216,320,215,317,215,313,214,312,212,312,210,312,208,314,205,317,204,319,203,323,201,323,201,323,198,322,196,318,195,313,193,311,191,311,189,313,187,315,183,316,180,318,179,321,181,324,183,327,185,331,186,334,185,336,183,336,182,337,174,333,174,330,173,329,173,326,173,323,172,321,171,321,169,321,167,322,165"
              href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/west_bengal/" alt="West Bengal">


        <area tabindex="-1" shape="poly" id="hoverregion_36"
              coords="312,60, 312,110, 410, 110, 410, 60"
              href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/ai" alt="Post Ad">


    </map>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#regions a").add("area").mouseover(function () {
            var id = this.id.substring(this.id.indexOf("_") + 1);
            var regionmap = $("#hoverregion_" + id);
            if (regionmap && regionmap.length > 0) {
                $("#area_highlight").removeClass().addClass("sprite_index_in_in_hover_region" + id);
                $("#region_" + id).css("text-decoration", "underline");
            }
        });
        $("#regions a").add("area").mouseout(function () {
            var id = this.id.substring(this.id.indexOf("_") + 1);
            var regionmap = $("#hoverregion_" + id);
            if (regionmap && regionmap.length > 0) {
                $("#area_highlight").removeClass();
                $("#region_" + id).css("text-decoration", "none");
            }
        });
    });</script>


</div>



html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font: inherit;
    z-index:6;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote::before, blockquote::after, q::before, q::after {
    content: none;
}





a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_left_right, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_left_right {
    width: 9px;
    height: 26px;
}

a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_right_left, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_right_left {
    width: 9px;
    height: 26px;
}

a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_left_left, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_left_left {
    width: 9px;
    height: 26px;
}

a:hover .sprite_common_pagi_right_right, a:hover.sprite_common_pagi_right_right {
    width: 9px;
    height: 26px;
}

a:hover .sprite_common_topbar_settings, a:hover.sprite_common_topbar_settings {
    width: 35px;
    height: 24px;
}



#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 948px;
    margin: 16px auto;
    text-align: left;
}


.js .topbar-dropdown a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.js .topbar-dropdown a, .js .topbar-dropdown a:visited, .js .topbar-dropdown a:hover {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a span:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:link {
    color: rgb(51, 102, 153);
}

a:visited {
    color: rgb(153, 51, 102);
}


.columns {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 1%;
}

.columns .widecolumn {
    width: 730px;
    float: left;
}

.columns aside {
    width: 202px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.spritetext {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

.nohistory a, a.nohistory, a .nohistory {
    color: rgb(51, 102, 153);
}

ul.bullets li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -16px;
    background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
    content: '';
    background-position: initial initial;
    background-repeat: initial initial;
}

header {
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(242, 102, 59);
}

footer {
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: rgb(242, 102, 59);
}

.main {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}


.column_left {
    width: 420px;
}

.box {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 320px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 2px 2px 8px;
    background-position: initial initial;
    background-repeat: initial initial;
}

.box h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.box ul {
    padding-left: 16px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.box li {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#regions {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

#regions .regions_one, #regions .regions_two {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#regions h2 {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding: 12px 0px 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#regions ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#regions ul li {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#regions a {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#mapcontainer {
    position: relative;
      float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:2;
}

#area_map {
    width: 450px;
    height: 499px;
}

#map_map img {
float: left;
    margin: 16px 0px 0px 32px;
}

.google_plus {
    position: absolute;
    right: 160px;
    top: 595px;
}

.sprite_index_in2_in_map {
     float: left;
    width: 450px;
    height: 499px;
    background: url("/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26") no-repeat -2px -2px;
}
```

...

```
.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region13 {
    width: 14px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url("/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26") no-repeat -856px -164px;
}

.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region24 {
    width: 48px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url("/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26") no-repeat -885px -193px;
}

.sprite_123plate_c_tl {
    width: 8px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url("/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26") no-repeat -456px -489px;
}

.sprite_123plate_c_tr {
    width: 8px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url("/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26") no-repeat -856px -187px;
}

.sprite_123plate_c_bl {
    width: 8px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url("/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26") no-repeat -856px -201px;
}

.sprite_123plate_c_br {
    width: 8px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url("/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26") no-repeat -856px -215px;
}

.sprite_x_repeat_howtobox_top_xr {
    background: url("/img/x_repeat_in.png?74db94879a19673b25ac5e0b63625bc0e07fb844") repeat-x 0px 0px;
}

.sprite_x_repeat_bar_xr {
    background: url("/img/x_repeat_in.png?74db94879a19673b25ac5e0b63625bc0e07fb844") repeat-x 0px -10px;
}

.sprite_x_repeat_in_in_insert_ad_xr {
    background: url("/img/x_repeat_in.png?74db94879a19673b25ac5e0b63625bc0e07fb844") repeat-x 0px -10px;
}

.sprite_x_repeat_progress_xr {
    background: url("/img/x_repeat_in.png?74db94879a19673b25ac5e0b63625bc0e07fb844") repeat-x 0px -62px;
}

.sprite_x_repeat_howtobox_bottom_xr {
    background: url("/img/x_repeat_in.png?74db94879a19673b25ac5e0b63625bc0e07fb844") repeat-x 0px -62px;
}

#regions {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

#regions .regions_one, #regions .regions_two {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#regions h2 {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding: 12px 0 4px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#regions ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#regions ul li {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#regions a {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.sprite_index_in_in_hover_post {
    margin-left: 129px;
    margin-top: 293px;
}


.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region8 {
    margin-left: 129px;
    margin-top: 293px;
}

.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region9 {
    margin-left: 361px;
    margin-top: 121px;
}
...
.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region29 {
    margin-left: 23px;
    margin-top: 118px;
}


.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region32 {
    margin-left: 360px;
    margin-top: 211px;
}

.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region33 {
    margin-left: 142px;
    margin-top: 115px;
}

.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region34 {
    margin-left: 147px;
    margin-top: 95px;
}

.sprite_index_in_in_hover_region35 {
    margin-left: 277px;
    margin-top: 166px;
}    


article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}


.sprite_index_in_in_map {
    z-index:3;
    width: 450px;
    height: 499px;
    clear: both;
    position: static;
    background: url(/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26) no-repeat -2px -2px;
}


.sprite_index_in_in2_map {
    float: left;

    width: 450px;
    height: 499px;
    background: url(/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26) no-repeat -2px -2px;
}

.sprite_index_in_in_en_logo {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 138px;
    background: url(/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26) no-repeat -1010px -27px;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 948px;
    margin: 16px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

header {
    display: block;
    height: 141px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.js .ie6 .topbar-dropdown {
    width: 160px;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown li {
    margin: 0;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 9px 17px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 20px;
    float: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown a span, .js .topbar-dropdown a i {
    float: left;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown .topbar-dropdown i {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown .topbar-settings {
    border-right: none;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown .sprite_common_topbar_dropdown-settings, .js .topbar-dropdown .sprite_common_topbar_dropdown-logout {
    margin: 3px 6px 0 0;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown .topbar-logout {
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-left: none;
}

.js .sprite_common_topbar_dropdown-arrow {
    float: right;
    margin: 7px 0 0 6px;
}

.js .sprite_common_topbar_logged-in, .js .sprite_common_topbar_log-in, .js .sprite_common_topbar_settings, .js .sprite_common_topbar_settings_active {
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.js .sprite_common_topbar_logged-in {
    margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.js .topbar-float_left {
    float: left;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown a, .js .topbar-dropdown a:visited, .js .topbar-dropdown a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.js .topbar-dropdown-button {
    width: 41px;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "myfont";
    src: url("/_/css/ITCAvantGardePro-Bk.woff") format('woff');
}
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'myfont', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a span:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
}

a:visited {
    color: #936;
}

strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}

p {
    margin: 12px 0;
}

p.first {
    margin-top: 0;
}

p.last {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul, ol {
    margin: 12px 0;
    padding-left: 32px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 4px 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 183.300003%;
    line-height: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 22px;
}

i {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-style: normal;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}



.button:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: 0 to(#f4f4f4));
    background-image: 0;
    background-image: 0;
    background-image: 0 color-stop(100%, #f4f4f4));
    background-image: 0;
    background-image: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #f4f4f4);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:active {
    background: #e0e0e0;
}





input[type=button]:active, input[type=submit]:active, button:active {
    background: #e0e0e0;
}

label.small {
    width: 90px;
}

label.large {
    width: 170px;
}

label.radio {
    margin-left: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.columns {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 1%;
}

.columns .widecolumn {
    width: 730px;
    float: left;
}

.columns aside {
    width: 202px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.visible {
    display: block !important;
}

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}





ul.bullets li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -16px;
    background: #c00;
    content: "";
}





.topbar-inner a {
}

header {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}


.main {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.column_left {
      float: left;
}

.box {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffc801;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 8px 0px 8px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.box h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.box ul {
    padding-left: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}

.box li {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

#regions {
    float: left;
    z-index:5;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-weight: 500; /* medium */
}

#regions .regions_one, #regions .regions_two {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#regions h2 {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding: 12px 0 4px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#regions ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#regions ul li {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#regions a {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 500; /* medium */
}

#mapcontainer {
     margin: 16px 0 0 32px;
    position: relative;
}

#area_map {
    width: 450px;
    height: 499px;
}

#map_map img #map_map_map .map_map_map{
      float: left;
    margin: 16px 0px 0px 32px;
    z-index:91;
}
```

Comment: You have 5k rep - PLEASE show only relevant bits of code (instead of hundreds of useless lines) and, if you can, create a live example.

Comment: @Shomz I'll make a minimal example if I can. It can take hours to create a minimal example therefore I will award a bounty if you save me this time since the solution can be simple for a trained eye even if there are thousands of lines somebody can know exactly what the mistake is. I know I should make a minimal example but it takes long time. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Well, that's pretty hard for any eye to see. I wrote you in my answer the only thing that looked odd, but browsers usually just use the last defined value in such cases. Everything else seems fine from a glance. Not sure how related this is, but I see no flicker here: http://avantgardecssfiddlezzz.montaoproject.appspot.com/

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other element overlapping? Maps can be tricky laying out hot spots that don't interfere with eachother.

Comment: I managed to lift out the bug in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/e0a4sb5g/ still too many lines of code but I can reduce it to a minimal code that contains the bug according to recommendations (minimal example) so that we can solve it.

Comment: I've fixed it... took me ages... Are you giving that bounty or not? :)

Comment: @Shomz Perfect! You're a hero. Expect 150 (or 200) bounty asap (I think I must wait 8 hours to award bounty).

Comment: @909Niklas Thank you, sir!! I wasn't really serious about the bounty, no worries. :) I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: I promise you bounty in 23 hours. (Since I would not have solved this problem easily myself.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is wrong, it removes and adds classes on each pointer move:

```
$("#area_highlight").removeClass().addClass("sprite_index_in_in_hover_region" + id);
```

---

This was the key: the div containing the images was constantly growing/shrinking based on its child elements. When I moved the "hover recognition" image out of it (so it's always there, responding to hovers) and set the div's pointer-event to none and position to absolute, it started to look good:

```
<div class="sprite_index_in_in_map" style="pointer-events: none; position: absolute;">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOPr+AAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" id="area_highlight" alt="">                
</div>
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/p81khp4e/

Comment: I'm giving you plusses for sticking with it this long.

Comment: Nice and tidier example too. Jeez that was messy.

Comment: @Christina Haha, thank you so much!! I feel like a celebrity today! :) The code is still quite messy and not to my liking, but at least it's getting somewhere.

Comment: I was amazed to see use of image maps, some how I've avoided them since the days of spacer.gifs. I'm old.

Comment: Exactly! Looks like something taken from the 90s vault that nobody dared to recreate. Shame, it would be quite interesting seeing it make use of modern technologies, say canvas and CSS3 animations.

Comment: Thank you for the information that we should ideally switch from image maps to svg / canvas / css. And use solar cell-powered datacenter because oil and such energy sources are not modern. The dhtml is succesfully checked by `http://validator.w3.org/` (which a `<center>` tag wouldn't pass). "The great rewrite" changing to a svg / canvas / css is probably not a good idea right now but of course we'll try and make maps with svg and css when upgrading or for new maps (we got a [us map](http://www.hipheap.com)) that is not an image map.  Image maps are not perfect.

Comment: Are you being ironic with the solar power and "the great rewrite"?

Comment: We should have solar power and the great rewrite but we can't right now. I think that solar power and "the great rewrite" are very good ideas. But they are large project and long-term projects. Economically we can't do it right now. A technically inferior solution can be more profitable right now. In the long term I believe we will have solar powered cheap energy and a great rewrite with svg maps, but the onlye maps I found with svg used heavy loads of javscript. I also tried with google maps but they can't allow a custom design. So it will be svg maps but we can't right now.

Comment: Understood, my comment was based on how all such maps seem to have been written in the 90s and never touched since. And there is a huge potential to make them look and behave really fancy. :) Look what I found, it might be helpful: http://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=india